React Component Library - dispatcher is null useState upon running in React app
I am using vite, TS to created a react component library.
My main.tsx in component-library contains the following test component,
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const TestComponent = () => {
  console.log("CONTENT-TEST");
  const [yamlTemplate, setYamlTemplate] = useState<string>("test component");
  console.log("CONTENT", yamlTemplate);
  console.log("CONTENT-setTemplate", setYamlTemplate);

  return <div>Test Component</div>;
};

The library build is created using tsc && vite build and installed to an actual React project using npm install --save ../component-library. Upon running the project I get the following error,
dispatcher is null
useState@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2823:7
Qr@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46064:67
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22917:31

Its complaining on useState. However I am able to see the log CONTENT-TEST in the logs. Here is the code to the react app project,
import "./App.css";
import { TestComponent } from "component-library";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Can anyone please help resolve this issue?

EDIT: I should also mentioned that my react app is a javascript react project and not using TS and vite. It was created through CRA
Here is my vite config,
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";
import { libInjectCss } from "vite-plugin-lib-inject-css";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path, { extname, relative, resolve } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";
import { glob } from "glob";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    copyPublicDir: false,
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.tsx"),
      formats: ["cjs", "es"],         
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react", "react-dom"], 
      input: Object.fromEntries(
        glob
          .sync("src/**/*.{ts,tsx}", {
            ignore: ["src/**/*.d.ts"],
          })
          .map((file) => [
            relative("src", file.slice(0, file.length - extname(file).length)),
            fileURLToPath(new URL(file, import.meta.url)),
          ]),
      ),
      output: {
        assetFileNames: "assets/[name][extname]",
        entryFileNames: "[name].js",
        globals: {
           react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
         },
      },
    },
    sourcemap: true, 
    emptyOutDir: true, 
  },
  plugins: [react(), libInjectCss(), dts({ include: ["src"] })],    });

Here are the peer dependencies form package.json. These dependencies have the same version as the CRA react app project,
 "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },



We can check same react version in both component-library and main-react-app
Check for peerDependency in component library package.json

{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0"
  }
}

And then we can validate this version is same in main react-app
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0"
  }
}


We can re-install dependencies in both npm install

In Component Library we can check React is marked as an external dependency in component library to avoid bundling it multiple times
We can do so in vite.config.ts for the component library


import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), dts()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/main.tsx',
      name: 'ComponentLibrary',
      fileName: (format) => `component-library.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});


We can check for duplicates by one of two ways below - 
i. Run npm dedupe 
ii. Use Aliases in Webpack

resolve: {
  alias: {
    react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
  },
}

After making these changes we can rebuild component library and reinstall it in the main application.
Reference for additional checks: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/30520
https://www.dhiwise.com/post/how-to-resolve-the-error-react-dispatcher-is-null

Hi. I have added my vite config here so you can check and see if anything is wrong. My peer dependencies for comp-lib and react app are the same. And above I have edited one more comment that I created react app with CRA and is using js, not TS. since I did not mentioned it earlier. I am not sure if that will make much of difference. I tried adding the globals to rollup output and initially in externals I had react and react-jsx something which I replaced with React-DOM but that did not help unfortunately. Kindly lmk if you need me to post something else here if it helps? thank you

What worked for me was to create a React app with npm create vite@latest. One main difference is I am using TS and vite in this case and this seems to be compatible somehow and worked. I might actually check creating a React app with vite and JS and see if it works. If it works then the possible issue is in the packages installed by CRA as its dependencies.
